# Application (Slash) Command says "The application did not respond" when replying with Components

Tags: discord.net

Following the guide I found on the [Discord.Net documentation site](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_basics/message-components/select-menus.html), I've built a command with the following definition:

```vb
Imports Discord
Imports Discord.Interactions

Public Class TestCommands
    Inherits InteractionModuleBase(Of SocketInteractionContext)

    Public Property Commands As InteractionService
    Private _handler As CommandHandler

    Public Sub New(ByVal handler As CommandHandler)
        _handler = handler
    End Sub

    <SlashCommand("faq", "View frequently asked questions")>
    Public Async Function FAQ() As Task
        Dim FAQMenu As New SelectMenuBuilder
        Dim FAQSelect As New ComponentBuilder

        With FAQMenu
            .WithPlaceholder("What's your question?")
            .WithCustomId("faq_menu")
            .WithMinValues(1)
            .WithMaxValues(1)
            .AddOption("Question #1?", "faq1")
            .AddOption("Question #2?", "faq2")
            .AddOption("Question #3?", "faq3")
            .AddOption("Question #4?", "faq4")
        End With

        FAQSelect.WithSelectMenu(FAQMenu)

        Await ReplyAsync("Select one of the following Frequently Asked Questions:", components:=FAQSelect.Build)
    End Function
End Class
```

When I run my bot and type `/faq` in my Discord client, it correctly displays my selection menu, but right above it I see a message saying "The application did not respond"

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I'm guessing that the bot is waiting for the selection, and I understand that there's a short timeout for the bot to receive input, but I definitely don't want my users to see that and think that there's a problem with the bot. Is there a better way to post the select menu component to prevent this message from popping up?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to include the `CommandHandler` object definition. Perhaps *that's* where the timeout is occurring. There's a lot of unfinished code in here, but maybe it'll help diagnose why I'm getting this message:

```vb
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Imports Discord
Imports Discord.Interactions
Imports Discord.WebSocket
Imports Ichthus.Bot

Public Class CommandHandler
    Private ServerLogChannel As UInt64 = 0

    Public Async Function InitializeAsync() As Task
        ' add the public modules that inherit InteractionModuleBase<T> to the InteractionService
        Await Settings.BotCommands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), Settings.BotProvider)

        ' process the InteractionCreated payloads to execute Interactions commands
        AddHandler Settings.Bot.InteractionCreated, AddressOf HandleInteraction
        AddHandler Settings.Bot.ButtonExecuted, AddressOf HandleButton
        AddHandler Settings.Bot.SelectMenuExecuted, AddressOf HandleMenu

        ' process the command execution results
        AddHandler Settings.BotCommands.SlashCommandExecuted, AddressOf SlashCommandExecuted
        AddHandler Settings.BotCommands.ContextCommandExecuted, AddressOf ContextCommandExecuted
        AddHandler Settings.BotCommands.ComponentCommandExecuted, AddressOf ComponentCommandExecuted
    End Function

    Private Function ComponentCommandExecuted(ByVal Command As ComponentCommandInfo, ByVal Context As IInteractionContext, ByVal Result As IResult) As Task
        If Not Result.IsSuccess Then
            Select Case Result.[Error]
                Case InteractionCommandError.UnmetPrecondition

                Case InteractionCommandError.UnknownCommand

                Case InteractionCommandError.BadArgs

                Case InteractionCommandError.Exception

                Case InteractionCommandError.Unsuccessful

                Case Else

            End Select
        End If

        Return Task.CompletedTask
    End Function

    Private Function ContextCommandExecuted(ByVal Command As ContextCommandInfo, ByVal Context As IInteractionContext, ByVal Result As IResult) As Task
        If Not Result.IsSuccess Then
            Select Case Result.[Error]
                Case InteractionCommandError.UnmetPrecondition

                Case InteractionCommandError.UnknownCommand

                Case InteractionCommandError.BadArgs

                Case InteractionCommandError.Exception

                Case InteractionCommandError.Unsuccessful

                Case Else

            End Select
        End If

        Return Task.CompletedTask
    End Function

    Private Function SlashCommandExecuted(ByVal Command As SlashCommandInfo, ByVal Context As IInteractionContext, ByVal Result As IResult) As Task
        If Not Result.IsSuccess Then
            Select Case Result.[Error]
                Case InteractionCommandError.UnmetPrecondition

                Case InteractionCommandError.UnknownCommand

                Case InteractionCommandError.BadArgs

                Case InteractionCommandError.Exception

                Case InteractionCommandError.Unsuccessful

                Case Else

            End Select
        End If

        Return Task.CompletedTask
    End Function

    Private Async Function HandleInteraction(ByVal Interaction As SocketInteraction) As Task
        Try
            ' create an execution context that matches the generic type parameter of your InteractionModuleBase<T> modules
            Dim Context As New SocketInteractionContext(Settings.Bot, Interaction)
            Dim Result As IResult = Await Settings.BotCommands.ExecuteCommandAsync(Context, Settings.BotProvider)

            If Not Result.IsSuccess Then
                Select Case Result.[Error]
                    Case InteractionCommandError.UnmetPrecondition

                    Case Else

                End Select
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)

            ' if a Slash Command execution fails it is most likely that the original interaction acknowledgment will persist. It is a good idea to delete the original
            ' response, or at least let the user know that something went wrong during the command execution.
            If Interaction.Type = InteractionType.ApplicationCommand Then
                Interaction.GetOriginalResponseAsync().ContinueWith(Function(msg) msg.Result.DeleteAsync()).Wait()
            End If
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Async Function HandleMenu(ByVal Selection As SocketMessageComponent) As Task
        For Each Selected As String In Selection.Data.Values
            Select Case Selected
                Case "faq1"
                    Await Selection.RespondAsync("Response #1.")
                Case "faq2"
                    Await Selection.RespondAsync("Response #2.")
                Case "faq3"
                    Await Selection.RespondAsync("Response #3.")
                Case "faq4"
                    Await Selection.RespondAsync("Response #4.")
                Case Else
                    Await Selection.RespondAsync($"{Selection.User.Mention} has selected something I don't recognize")
            End Select
        Next Selected
    End Function

    Private Async Function HandleButton(ByVal Button As SocketMessageComponent) As Task
        Select Case Button.Data.CustomId
            Case "faq1"
                Await Button.RespondAsync($"{Button.User.Mention} has clicked the first button")
            Case "faq2"
                Await Button.RespondAsync($"{Button.User.Mention} has clicked the second button")
            Case "faq3"
                Await Button.RespondAsync($"{Button.User.Mention} has clicked the third button")
            Case Else
                Await Button.RespondAsync($"{Button.User.Mention} has clicked something I don't recognize")
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because you are not responding to the interaction. `ReplyAsync` simply sends a message to the channel it does not send a message in response to the interaction. As such, as far as Discord is concerned, your application did not respond, just as the error says. When using Slash Commands you should use `RespondAsync` to send a message in response to the command. `ReplyAsync` is meant for standard Text Commands.

Note that Slash Command responses usually look similar to how the error message is formatted in your image. The original command is shown at the top and the command response is shown immediately below it as if you used Discord's reply feature.

Comment: That makes total sense. The linked example in the documentation uses the `ReplyAsync()` method, which is why I used that in my testing, assuming it would "work". I just tried with the `RespondAsync()` method instead and that "fixes" it all. Thanks so much.